# org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive error on the second response

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I'm using the Android 2.1 API. I download from the web, through ksoap Protocol, the data. The result is this exception `org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive` and do not understand why.

with debugging, the `for` runs correctly the first round, but the second time it hangs education `re = (SoapObject) ((SoapObject) envelope.getResponse ()). getProperty (s)`, reporting the error `org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive`.

Here is the code:

```
request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("dev", false);
request.addProperty("Cap", input_cap.getText().toString());

envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE,Offerta.Offerta_CLASS.getSimpleName(),Offerta.Offerta_CLASS);

androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

int nOff = ((SoapObject) envelope.getResponse()).getPropertyCount();
SoapObject re;

for (int i = 0; i < nOff; i++) {
  re = (SoapObject) ((SoapObject) envelope.getResponse()).getProperty(i);
  img.setImageBitmap(getBitmap(Integer.parseInt(re.getProperty(0).toString())));
  titolo.setText(re.getProperty(1).toString());
  descrizioneTitolo.setText(re.getProperty(3).toString());
  provincia.setText(getProvincia(Integer.parseInt(re.getProperty(13).toString())));
  sintesi.setText(re.getProperty(2).toString());
  contenitore_paese.addView(view);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message sounds like your second property on the following line isn't a SoapObject but a Soap primitive, which is breaking it at runtime because you are type casting it.

```
re = (SoapObject) ((SoapObject) envelope.getResponse()).getProperty(i);
```

Comment: How is it possible? return the same objects from the web .... and I used the same mechanism in other classes and it works ...

However thanks a lot! I better recheck: P

Comment: I solved the problem :D I used common objects without realizing, thanks for answer!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Just cast to SoapPrimitive instead SoapObject. Also I don't know why, but if you see the code, it could be logical.

```
SoapPrimitive re = (SoapPrimitive)  envelope.getResponse().getProperty(i) ;
```